# What is the correct way of integrating Jquery Image Zoom Plugin with angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have made a directive to integrate elevate zoom plugin

```
.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
      $(element).elevateZoom();
    }
  };
});
```

and the html code is

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="product-thumbs">
              <a class="active" href="#" data-image="images/product/productd-1.jpg"  data-zoom-image="images/product/zoom/productd-1.jpg">
                <img src="images/product/thumb/productd-1.jpg" alt="productd-1">
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-image="images/product/productd-1.jpg"  data-zoom-image="images/product/zoom/productd-1.jpg">
                <img src="images/product/thumb/productd-1.jpg" alt="productd-1">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-display">
              <img id="zoom-1" src="images/product/productd-1.jpg" ng-elevate-zoom data-zoom-image="images/product/zoom/productd-1.jpg" alt="productd-1">
            </div>
```

The plugin is working fine in this page but when i navigate to other pages the plugin is still initialized and causing some problems. Can you provide me some suggestion how to remove this plugin from other pages or some solution regarding this usage of plugin.I have also attached screen shot of other pages after this plugin has been initialized.

[image: plugin on another pages]

Comment: Did you tried using isolated `scope` ?

Comment: No i have not used isolated scope. Can you provide me example to use isolated scope in this scenario.

Comment: In your return map just add a key like `scope:{}`. Something like `restrict: 'A',scope:{},---`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya it can be solved with destroying the instantiated object on destroy of your directive scope like given below example.

```
.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{}
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
      $(element).elevateZoom();
      // destroy your objects
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
           $('.zoomContainer').remove();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: have you destroyed the instance of zoom plugin inside function

Comment: i only get it working by removing the div which this plugin rendered i.e
$('.zoomContainer').remove(); on each controller

Comment: then just keep removing code in directive it will remove when scope gets desroyed

Comment: Thanks its working now, but i have a question is it the best way to destroy the object or rendered div??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97487/discussion-between-nglover-and-bittu).